# Sharepoint 2007 Image Gallery - Is there a better one available that I'm not seeing?

Tags: 2007, picture-library

The default image gallery for Sharepoint 2007 requires you to click the thumbnail of each picture you want to view and then after you see the picture, you have to navigate back to the thumbnails before you can continue to the next picture.

Is there a way to make this process easier so users can simply click next or use the arrow keys on their keyboard to quickly move forward and back between images in a gallery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look under the Actions menu, you'll see a "View Slide Show" option. That's what you get out of the box.

If you're looking for something a little more "modern", consider adding a jQuery-driven "lightbox". You see these all over the Web these days, and you and your users will be very familiar with them. You can use my [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) library to drive the slideshow by reading the list items using GetListItems.